# Homeomorphism of closed intervals

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

One can prove that if $f: [a,b] \to [f(a), f(b)]$ is continuous and monotone increasing that then it is a homeomorphism. The only part one might have to think about at all is that $f$ is open but that can be shown easily by showing that $f$ is closed: If $C=[x,y]$ is closed in $[a,b]$ then because $f$ is monotone, $z < x$ implies $f(z) < f(x)$ and similarly $z > y$ implies $f(z) > f(y)$ so that $f(C) = [f(x), f(y)]$ is closed.

Can this be generalised by requiring $f$ to only be increasing that is, $x \le y$ implies $f(x) \le f(y)$?

Comment: The constant function $f : [a, b] \to [f(a), f(b)] = \{f(a)\}$ is not a homeomorphism for $a \ne b$ but satisfies your conditions.

Comment: I think OP wants *stictly monotonic*.

Comment: No, newb specifically said s/he wanted to generalize by *removing* the strictness assumption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a valid generalisation, as mentioned in the comments, because if there are two points $x,y$ with $x<y$ but $f(x)=f(y)$, then $f$ is no longer injective and hence cannot be a homeomorphism because it is not a bijection. Aymen gave an example of such a function with this property which is any constant function because an interval is not homeomorphic to a single point (by cardinality arguments).